# How do i transfer bitcoins from bitcoin qt to multi bit?

Tags: client, multibit, money

Im very new to this so forgive me. I downloaded bitcoin qt and after 16 hours there was no progress whatsoever with this 'blockchain' stuff. I bought some bitcoins to send to the bitcoin qt client. which i cannot access. my question is how do i transfer the coins which i can't even access in qt to multi bit? I've found some other links on here which I've tried following but they don't work. Im on a macbook if this makes any difference. can someone please give me a step by step on how to transfer them to multi bit? or have i just wasted my money on those bitcoins? thank you

Comment: Obviously, just make a transaction from your QT wallet to an address created by multibit. If you are worried, send a small amount first to "test" it.

Comment: @T9b If he asked the question, then it wasn't obvious to him. He's not trying to annoy you; he didn't know.